# Can I see how close I am to earning a robocop hat?

Tags: discussion, review, winter-bash-2013

In the review queue "stats" page it has a count of how many reviews I have done in that queue today, and how many I have done in that queue ever, but I assume the Robocop hat is for reviews done since the start of the winter bash - am I right? So how would I determine how many more reviews I need to do in that queue? I haven't been keeping count myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to start counting then you can use the activity/reviews tab in your profile

https://stackoverflow.com/users/495796/robin-green?tab=activity&sort=reviews

Please don't do reviews *just* for a hat...

Comment: If those are good reviews then why not? I did some just for hats and don't think they were bad. Having a goal doesn't always mean doing it in a hurry or robo-reviewing.

Comment: If they are good reviews then there's no reason why not at all @Sha. But that implies that someone wants to do well, and cares about something other than just a hat.

Comment: @ShadowWizard And all this time I thought the Robocop hat _was_ for robo-reviewing!